# Swift error: Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments?

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading, reachability

Actually Iam checking for internet connection in my code and i get a weird error **"Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments"**

Here is my code snippet,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        checkkNetworkStatus()

        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://example")

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }


func checkkNetworkStatus(){

        let networkChecking : Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

        networkChecking.startNotifier()

        var status : NetworkStatus = networkChecking.currentReachabilityStatus()

        if (status == NotReachable)   ***//error***
        {
            // statement
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do
`if (status == .NotReachable)` or  `if (status == NetworkStatus.NotReachable)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your error lies in your if-statement:

```
if status == NotReachable
```

You have to rewrite it like this:

```
if status == .NotReachable
```

or this:

```
if status == NetworkStatus.NotReachable
```

`status` is an Enum value and you access the different properties of Enums in one of the two ways I wrote.

If you want to know more about enum, you should [check the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145)